# Zip file is not getting downloaded using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

I have a folder in which there are 3-4 PDF files. SO on button click, I want to download PDF files as a `ZIP` file. For that I have write the below code

```
string strFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/" + SAP_ID + '_' + CANDIDATEID + "\\" + SAP_ID + '_' + CANDIDATEID + ".pdf");
string strDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/" + SAP_ID + '_' + CANDIDATEID);

HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

if (Directory.Exists(strDirectory))
{
    if (File.Exists(strFilePath + ".zip"))
    {
        var filestream = new System.IO.FileStream(strFilePath + ".zip", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
        filestream.Close();
        File.Delete(strFilePath + ".zip");
     }                   
}

//  ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(strDirectory, strDirectory + ".zip");

var stream = new FileStream(strDirectory + ".zip", FileMode.Open);

result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(strDirectory + ".zip");
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
```

But on button click the ZIP is not getting downloaded and the browser just loads.

What might be the cause?

Comment: can you check whether the zip file was created on the server ?

Comment: @minhhn2910: ok let me check.!

Comment: @minhhn2910: No, Now when I debugged my code, I got error as `{"Could not find file 'D:\\UserName\\VSATFINAL_353\\VSATTSSRSurvey\\UploadedFiles\\I-BR-RNCH-ENB-0243_C3.zip'.` at line `var stream = new FileStream(strDirectory + ".zip", FileMode.Open);`

Comment: @minhhn2910: hey sorry actually it created at this line `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(strDirectory, strDirectory + ".zip");` i commented out that line. but when it already exist it gives error for me. so what should I do for this ?

Comment: @minhhn2910: Now my mainissue here the zip file is not getting downloaded, but yes the zip file is getting created.

Comment: ok, so Is the path `D:\\UserName\\VSATFINAL_353\\VSATTSSRSurvey\\UploadedFiles\‌\I-BR-RNCH-ENB-0243_‌​C3.zip` correct ? and Is that a subfolder in your web root folder? if not then it should be a permission problem like the answer below. OR ASP routing problem that makes the webserver could not find your file

Comment: Are you using MVC or web forms? If you are using MVC try FileResult or for web forms try Response.TransmitFile

Comment: @minhhn2910: no, its not permission problem and yes the path is perfect. I guess something other issue it is

Comment: @DavidLindon: its web form, could you please tell me how to use it ?

Comment: @minhhn2910: the code is working fine, still i cant see the zip file getting downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have more luck with the Response.TransmitFile method, here is an example using the address of your zip file -

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.zip");
Response.TransmitFile(strFilePath + ".zip");
Response.Flush();
```

Comment: let me try and check if I can get it

Comment: got this error `The process cannot access the file 'D:\UserName\VSATFINAL_353\VSATTSSRSurvey\UploadedFiles\I-MH-CLSG-ENB-0001_C3.zip' because it is being used by another process.` at line `HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(strDirectory + ".zip");`

Comment: Do you have any filestreams that aren't closed? I notice that you have a couple of lines that are now redundant - var stream = new FileStream(strDirectory + ".zip", FileMode.Open);
result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

Comment: may be, here is my full function for that. Do let me know show that I can remove the unwanted code. https://dotnetfiddle.net/DQChgv

Comment: Remove lines 223 and 235, these are opening filestreams that are not needed and will cause the above error

Comment: now getting error as `The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070040.` at line `HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();`

Comment: hey I removed both the last line, `HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();` and `HttpContext.Current.Response.End();` now I didnt got any error. also the file got downloaded but it was as like this **D--UserName-VSATFINAL_353-VSATTSSRSurvey-UploadedFiles-I-MH-CLSG-ENB-0001_C3 (1)** not the zip file though. why ?

Comment: Ah, the filename (download name) is set in this line - `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.zip");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150326/discussion-between-vvvv-and-david-lindon).

Answer (score 0):

If the zip file isn't getting created you probably need to grant write/modify permissions on your UploadedFiles directory to IIS AppPool\yourAppPoolName .

Comment: hey, Zip file is getting created but not getting downloaded